# Stymied by idle_in_transaction_session_timeout

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore

Immediate problem:  When I do a pgAdmin 4 restore I get "Stymied by idle_in_transaction_session_timeout" error.

I am on a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave version 10.14.5, using Java and PostgreSQL.  I use the pgAdmin 4 GUI, as I am not proficient in psql, bash, etc.  I have a test database named pg2.  As you can see from the attachment, PostgreSQL servers 9.4 and 10 have the identical databases.  If I make a change in a database on one server, it will show also in the other server’s database.  There is a third server, 11, in which there is only the postgres database.

I have tried psql and get errors (including timeout errors).
I have tried to Delete/Drop server 11, it will disappear but when I sign out of pgAdmin 4 and then go into pgAdmin 4 again the server 11 will be there again.

See the attachments for screen shots.

I expect the backup/restore to work: backup, then make a change to the database, then correctly restore to previous state.

I would like to have just one server, preferably 11 with only pg1 and the test db tempdb running in it.  I thought that I could live with the three, for I am aware of my current capabilities and thus did not want to screw things up further.  However, I suspect that the two servers 9.4 and 10 are the source of my current problem:  receiving the idle_in_transaction_session_timeout error while doing a restore.  Note:  I did the backup using the server 10’s pg1 backup.  Did it create 2 backups, one for 9.4 and one for 10?

Comment: Sorry, this is too muddled to understand.

Answer (score 0):

[image]I tried to attach these before.  They will help make sense of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 servers have the same database; is this causing the idle in transaction session timeout?[image]